# Gentoo Dns and proxy configuration

Tags: system-installation, gentoo, proxy

I was trying to install gentoo on my laptop but i'm unable to get internet to work on it:

In my network, i can surf only through a specified proxy server so i configured proxy server using " export http_proxy="http://---------" but the problem is that all the dns request are fulfilled by proxy ie i dont have any dns server availabile.

Now i can't use links it says host not found..So how do i configure dns over proxy while installing gentoo..

Answer (score 0):

I found this link: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/ProxyAutoConfig
I hope if is useful.